# PHP reading a json array value

Tags: php, json

I am working on making a website that will display a list of the states and then a sublist of each national park in that state. I am currently able to get the states to show up, and the correct number of sublist elements to appear (the correct number of bullet points show up for the corresponding number of parks in each state), but I am unable to get the park name and url to work. I did this a couple weeks ago in Javascript, but now I need it in php.

Here is a sample of my array:

```
{
    "stateParks": [
    {"state": "Alabama", "parks": []},
    {"state": "Alaska", "parks": [{"parkName":"Denali", "url":"https://www.nps.gov/dena/index.htm"},{"parkName":"Glacier Bay", "url":"https://www.nps.gov/glba/index.htm"}]},
```

And here is my current php:

```
<?php
$jsonData = file_get_contents("../data/stateParks.json");
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsonData, true);
$output = '<ul class="stateParks">';

foreach($jsonDecoded['stateParks'] as $statePark)
{
    $counter = 0;
    $output .= '<li class="superlist">'.$statePark['state'].'<ul>';
    foreach($statePark['parks'] as $parks)
    {
        $output .= '<li class="sublist"><a href="'.$parks[$counter]['url'].'">'.$parks[$counter]['parkName'].'</a></li>';
        $counter++;
    }
    $output .= '</ul></li>';
}
$output .= '</ul>';
echo $output;

?>
```

This is an assignment, so I would appreciate if you didn't tell me the direct answer because I want to make sure I understand what is wrong and I don't like cheating. But any pointers, tips, and hints are very appreciated.

Comment: In second foreach loop print your values using print_r($parks); to see the correct array structure. Try that first.

Comment: remove `[$counter]` from `$output .= '<li class="sublist"><a href="'.$parks[$counter]['url'].'">'.$parks[$counter]['parkName'].'</a></li>';` use this: `$output .= '<li class="sublist"><a href="'.$parks['url'].'">'.$parks['parkName'].'</a></li>';`

Comment: Gave me this, which seems to be correct: Array ( [parkName] => Denali [url] => https://www.nps.gov/dena/index.htm ) Array ( [parkName] => Glacier Bay [url] => https://www.nps.gov/glba/index.htm ) .........

Comment: Thank you Gaurav. I am new to using foreach loops, so I thought we would still have to give it a value. I was fairly sure that that was the error, but didn't think we could jsut get rid of the counter

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove $counter

```
use $parks['url'] instead $parks[$counter]['url']
```

and

```
use $parks['parkName'] instead $parks[$counter]['parkName']
```